# Do Vengeful Strike and/or Valiant Strike count as melee basic attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

Would the at-will abilities *Vengeful Strike* and *Valiant Strike* count as melee basic attacks?

I am asking because the purple dragon *Focused Discipline* stance gives +1 power bonus to 
melee basic attacks.

Comment: Well, what do the powers say? Does *Vengeful Strike* or *Valiant Strike* say they count as melee basic attacks?

Answer (score 4):

For a power to count as a Melee Basic Attack it must say "This attack counts as a melee basic attack" this is a difference from "Can be used in place of a Melee basic attack."

Neither of these powers indicates that they can be used as or count as melee basic attacks, so no, under normal circumstances, they neither count as nor can be used as melee basic attacks. There may be feats or other features that allow them to be (for instance, as [webbcode](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15129/webbcode) points out the Power of Skill feat can allow Valient Strike to be *used as* a MBA) , but by themselves, they are just standard action powers that involve attacks.

Comment: A player with the Power of Skill feat (requires worshipping a deity with the skill domain, such as Ioun) can use Valiant Strike as a Melee Basic Attack.

Comment: Feel like this answer is missing the fact that a "Melee Basic Attack" is a specific power that all characters have, not some sort of general concept of "melee attacks that are simple", which is not obvious to a new player.